# Loop through array of values and sort

Tags: php, for-loop, if-statement

I would like you to help me with an algorithm in PHP that can loop through an array of values, sort them and print non-duplicates.

Here is the code I wrote. I want to do it with only loop and if else statement. I would appreciate any help in achieving this. Thanks

```php
    $input_array = [3, 5, 7, 7, 8, 3, 1, 9, 9, 9, 0, 2, 4, 8, 0, 12, 5, 8, 2];`
    $count_array = count($input_array); // count the array`enter code here`
    for($i = 0; $i < $count_array; $i++){ //loop through the array 1st time
        $check_array = false;
       
        //sort array
        for($j = $i+1; $j < $count_array; $j++){
           
            if($input_array[$i] > $input_array[$j]){
                $non_duplicates = $input_array[$i];
                $input_array[$i] = $input_array[$j];
                $input_array[$j] = $non_duplicates;
                    
            }
    
            else if($input_array[$i] == $input_array[$j] &&( $i != $j)){ 
                $check_array = true;
                break;
            }
    
            else{
                $input_array[$i] != $input_array[$j];
            }
    
        }  
    
         if(!$check_array){
            echo($input_array[$i]. ', ');
         }   
        
    }
```

Comment: why not  array_unique() ?

Comment: I want to do it without using inbuilt array functions. If i used it i could have gotten the answer easily

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with 2 `for` cycles where the first cycle is for the first element and the 2nd cycle is always in the next position, this will help to always check if the first number is less than the second. You create a temporary variable where you store the value of the first number and you pass the value of the second number to the variable of the first one, later the temporary one that you had stored you pass it to the variable of the second number (with this you got to invert the values of one to the other).

As this is ordering them, later an if is made where it is verified if they are equal, in case of being equal a `unset()` is made to eliminate that data of the array.

```
// Array of values
$input_array = [3, 5, 7, 7, 8, 3, 1, 9, 9, 9, 0, 2, 4, 8, 0, 12, 5, 8, 2];
// count the length of array
$count = count($input_array);
// order array and remove duplicates
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    for ($j = $i + 1; $j < $count; $j++) {
        // order array
        if ($input_array[$i] < $input_array[$j]) {
            $temp = $input_array[$i];
            $input_array[$i] = $input_array[$j];
            $input_array[$j] = $temp;
        }
        // delete duplicates
        if ($input_array[$i] == $input_array[$j]) {
            unset($input_array[$j]);
        }
    }
}
// Return an array with elements in reverse order
$input_array = array_reverse($input_array);
```

You get something like this:

```
 Dump => array(9) {
  [0] => int(1)
  [1] => int(2)
  [2] => int(3)
  [3] => int(4)
  [4] => int(7)
  [5] => int(5)
  [6] => int(8)
  [7] => int(9)
  [8] => int(12)
}
```

Comment: I actually want it to in a sort out the array and print out non-duplicating values all without using inbuilt functions. So the output according to the array should be [1, 2, 4, 12];